# Cordova geolocation not detecting enabling location with Android quick-settings drop-down

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

In a cordova app I try to use `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` (cordova-plugin-geolocation) on Android, but when the Location is disabled when the app is started, and I enable it by using the quick-settings dropdown menu, my app doesn't detect this.

But when I go to the home-screen and come back to my app, the GPS *does* work.

Any idea how to get it detecting the Location from the quick-settings drop down?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, is a dialog to allow you turn on/off **Location** setting directly from the app: https://github.com/rodrigo-martinezd/cordova-dialog-gps

In alternative you need to intercept change from app and fire a **location.reload()** from javascript. You can try this solution from chrome inspector attached to your app. Turn location ON from settings menu of device, then fire a **location.reload()** from inspector consolle.

Is because plugin check on initialization the state of Location settings, but not watch its changes after initialization..

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [registerLocationStateChangeHandler()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#registerlocationstatechangehandler) of [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to detect the changes made to location mode via quick settings while your Android app is in the foreground:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler(function(locationMode){
     switch(locationMode){
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.locationMode.HIGH_ACCURACY:
            console.log("High accuracy");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.locationMode.BATTERY_SAVING:
            console.log("Battery saving");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.locationMode.DEVICE_ONLY:
            console.log("Device only");
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.locationMode.LOCATION_OFF:
            console.log("Location off");
            break;
    }
});
```